# Azure SQL: Delete User records with redundant nested references

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database, subquery

I have a quite complex requirement to delete `UserSubscriptions` records with redundant options, meaning if a UserId is associated with two or more subscriptions with same options I need to keep the first subscription and then delete the rest of the subscriptions, below are some of the scenarions.

Scenario 1: UserId 1 has three subscriptions (SubscriptionId 1, 2 and 3) and all of the subscriptions have same options (Email, Call, Fax) so for UserId 1 so the SubscriptionOptionIds 4,5,6,7,8,9 have to be deleted from UserSubscriptions

Scenario 2: UserId 2 has two subscriptions (SubscriptionId 1 and 2) and both the subscriptions DOES NOT have same options in this case nothing needs to be deleted

Scenarion 3: UserId 3 has two subscriptions (SubscriptionId 1 and 2) and  both the subscriptions have same option (Email) so for UserId 3 so the SubscriptionOptionId 3 has to be deleted from UserSubscriptions

Below is my Table's DDL+DML

```
CREATE TABLE [Options](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  
    [Name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL
    
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [Options] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_Options] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [Subscriptions](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  
    [Name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [Subscriptions] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_Subscriptions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


CREATE TABLE [SubscriptionsOptions](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [OptionId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SubscriptionId] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [SubscriptionsOptions] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_SubscriptionsOptions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [SubscriptionsOptions]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_SubscriptionsOptions.SubscriptionId_Subscriptions.Id] FOREIGN KEY([SubscriptionId])
REFERENCES [Subscriptions] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [SubscriptionsOptions] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_SubscriptionsOptions.SubscriptionId_Subscriptions.Id]
GO
ALTER TABLE [SubscriptionsOptions]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_SubscriptionsOptions.OptionId_Options.Id] FOREIGN KEY([OptionId])
REFERENCES [Options] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [SubscriptionsOptions] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_SubscriptionsOptions.OptionId_Options.Id]
GO


CREATE TABLE [UserSubscriptions](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SubscriptionsOptionsId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [userid] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [UserSubscriptions] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_UserSubscriptions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [UserSubscriptions]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_UserSubscriptions.SubscriptionsOptionsId_SubscriptionsOptions.Id] FOREIGN KEY([SubscriptionsOptionsId])
REFERENCES [SubscriptionsOptions] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [UserSubscriptions] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_UserSubscriptions.SubscriptionsOptionsId_SubscriptionsOptions.Id]
GO


INSERT INTO Options VALUES ('E-mail');
INSERT INTO Options VALUES ('Call');
INSERT INTO Options VALUES ('Fax');

INSERT INTO Subscriptions VALUES ('Promo1');
INSERT INTO Subscriptions VALUES ('Promo2');
INSERT INTO Subscriptions VALUES ('Promo3');

INSERT INTO SubscriptionsOptions VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO SubscriptionsOptions VALUES (1,2);
INSERT INTO SubscriptionsOptions VALUES (1,3);
INSERT INTO SubscriptionsOptions VALUES (2,1);
INSERT INTO SubscriptionsOptions VALUES (2,2);
INSERT INTO SubscriptionsOptions VALUES (2,3);
INSERT INTO SubscriptionsOptions VALUES (3,1);
INSERT INTO SubscriptionsOptions VALUES (3,2);
INSERT INTO SubscriptionsOptions VALUES (3,3);

INSERT INTO UserSubscriptions VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO UserSubscriptions VALUES (1,2);
INSERT INTO UserSubscriptions VALUES (1,3);
INSERT INTO UserSubscriptions VALUES (1,4);
INSERT INTO UserSubscriptions VALUES (1,5);
INSERT INTO UserSubscriptions VALUES (1,6);
INSERT INTO UserSubscriptions VALUES (1,7);
INSERT INTO UserSubscriptions VALUES (1,8);
INSERT INTO UserSubscriptions VALUES (1,9);
INSERT INTO UserSubscriptions VALUES (2,1);
INSERT INTO UserSubscriptions VALUES (2,2);
INSERT INTO UserSubscriptions VALUES (2,3);
INSERT INTO UserSubscriptions VALUES (2,4);
INSERT INTO UserSubscriptions VALUES (2,5);
INSERT INTO UserSubscriptions VALUES (3,1);
INSERT INTO UserSubscriptions VALUES (3,3);
```

**Options**

```
1   E-mail
2   Call
3   Fax
```

**Subscriptions**

```
1 Promo1
2 Promo2
3 Promo3
```

**SubscriptionsOptions**

```
id SubscriptionId OptionId
1   1           1
2   1           2
3   1           3
4   2           1
5   2           2
6   2           3
7   3           1
8   3           2
9   3           3
```

**UserSubscriptions**

```
userid SubscriptionOptionId
1           1
1           2
1           3
1           4
1           5
1           6
1           7
1           8
1           9

2           1
2           2
2           3
2           4
2           5

3           1
3           3
```

The final output of `UserSubscriptions` has to be like below, am having hard time for the deletion script for the above mentioned scenarios, I really appreciate if someone can help me with the deletion script

```
userid SubscriptionOptionId
1           1
1           2
1           3

2           1
2           2
2           3
2           4
2           5

3           1
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: @Dale K  I tried my best to be as detail as possible, what part of the question needs more details?

Comment: You don't actually ask a question... you list your requirements (which isn't a question). You don't tell us what you tried, or where you are stuck.

Comment: `"Below are my tables"` - these are not tables but text. Please provide DDL+DML (meaning queries to create the tables and insert the sample data).

Comment: @RonenAriely My bad, I just updated the question with the DDL+DML

Comment: Thanks for proving the DDL+DML. can you elaborate where is the UserID? there is no table for users and all your "id" has the same name = "id" (which is a different discussion about best names to use). SO in this sample three tables, what is considered as your UserID?

Comment: @RonenAriely In sample there are 4 tabled and `UserSubscriptions` table stores many to many associations between `User` table and `SubscriptionOptions` and `UserID`  values are present in `UserSubscriptions` table. Since the `User` table is irrelavant here I didnt include it in the question

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement does not seem to match your expected output.

Your requirement says "delete `UserSubscriptions` records with redundant options, meaning if a `UserId` is associated with two or more subscriptions with same options I need to keep the first subscription and then delete the rest of the subscriptions". But in your expected output that is not satisfied.

For example, in your expected output you have deleted `subscriptionOptionId` 4 from `userId` 1, but you have not deleted it from `userId` 2. Why not?

Conversely, for `userId` 3 you have deleted `subscriptionOptionId` 3 from `userSubscrptions`, but `subscriptionOptionId` 1 has `optionId` 1, whereas `subscriptionOptionId` 3 has `optionId` 3. These are different options, so according to your requirement neither should have been deleted.

A query which actually deletes rows according to your stated requirement (but which will not produce your expected result) would be:

```
delete   sub
from     userSubscriptions      sub 
join     SubscriptionsOptions   opt on opt.id = sub.SubscriptionsOptionsId
where    exists 
         (
            select *
            from   userSubscriptions    prevSub
            join   SubscriptionsOptions prevOpt on prevOpt.Id = prevSub.SubscriptionsOptionsId
            where  prevSub.userId = sub.userId
                   and prevSub.id < sub.id
         )
```

Having said that, if I think about what this is modelling a little bit, I think the semantics of your requirements as described aren't really what you want. If I, as a user, am subscribed to two different promotions, it seems sensible that I could have both of those promotions use the same delivery option.

However, what *would* be redundant would be a situation where I am subscribed to a promotion, and the database says that I want that promo sent to me in a particular way, and it says it twice. For example, "allmhuran is subscribed to promo1 and wants it delivered by email", and "allmhuran is subscribed to promo1 and wants it delivered by email".

But there are no such redundancies in your sample data, because there are no redundancies in your `subscriptionsOptions` table. Every row is a unique combination of `{subscriptionId, optionId}`.

On the off chance that this is what you actually wanted to do, the delete statement only changes slightly:

```
delete   sub
from     userSubscriptions      sub 
join     SubscriptionsOptions   opt on opt.id = sub.SubscriptionsOptionsId
where    exists 
         (
            select *
            from   userSubscriptions    prevSub
            join   SubscriptionsOptions prevOpt on prevOpt.Id = prevSub.SubscriptionsOptionsId
            where  prevSub.userId = sub.userId
                   and prevOpt.subscriptionId = opt.subscriptionId -- this condition was not in the previous statement
                   and prevSub.id < sub.id
         )
```

If that is the intention, then I would also say that the existing schema is "overnormalized". All you really need is a `UserSubscriptionOptions` table `(userId int, subscriptionId int, optionId int, primary key (userId, subscriptionId, optionId)`

Answer (score 0):

This is simpler than it seems:

1. Create a view over UserSubscriptions joined to SubscriptionOptions
2. Order by user, than as desired e.g. from "earliest" to "latest"
3. Add a hash across user id and option id
4. For each duplicate hash delete the corresponding SubscriptionOptions row
5. Once done, delete any Subscriptions rows with no corresponding SubscriptionOptions rows

This is doable in SQL or the imperative language of your choice.